# Why does "exit" require parentheses?

Tags: php

If `echo` can work withouth the parentheses why `exit` can't?

Comment: Well, that are the quirks of PHP.

Comment: ...because PHP is a mess. (No flamewar intended.) =)

Comment: Tell us what other language is used for server side web development and holds more market share ?

Comment: @Robert, bandwagon fallacy anyone?   PHP is certainly widely used, but that really doesn't mean it's well-designed.

Comment: @Robert I said *No flamewar intended*, so please keep calm (I saw you getting worked up in your now deleted comment). :) I'm a full-time PHP developer and I actually *like* it. It still *is* a mess. =)

Comment: Yea i deleted it, its too early for me that's all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They're both language constructs (T_ECHO and T_EXIT), but different kinds.  You *can* use exit without parentheses, but not if you're passing a value.  Another quirk is that echo requires you *not* to use parentheses if you pass more than one value:

```
php > echo 'foo', 'bar';
foobar
php > echo ('foo', 'bar');
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in php shell code on line 1
```

If you're now thinking, "But that doesn't really explain *why* the design is inconsistent", welcome to PHP.

Comment: Brilliant! Is there any particular reason `exit` was designed to require parentheses when passed a value?

Comment: can you think of a function that **doesn't** require parentheses when passing a value?

Comment: Maybe so it can be used safely (and without confusion) within other statements: `mysql_connect( ... ) or exit( 'blabla' );` or something like that (personally I prefer to use the equivalent `die` in such cases though). – Or maybe because it looks more similar to the C equivalent `exit()` then..

Comment: @Ross: No, but I can think of another language construct that doesn't require parentheses - `echo`.

Comment: Casts do not require parenthesis, e.g. `(int) $a`

Comment: @Emanuil, I doubt it.  Personal Home Page Tools was influenced by both C and Perl, and in this case perhaps Lerdorf chose the C syntax.  @Ross, it's not a function.  @poke, that syntax works in Perl without the latter parentheses.

Comment: @Matthew, I wonder why this inconsistency hasn't been addressed yet. Addressing it wouldn't hurt backward compatibility so what other reason can it be?

Answer (score 7):

Simply because somebody programmed it as such, and nobody bothered to change it. Echo and exit do not share code, so they do not necessarily work the same way. There is no good reason for this.

Here is some code from PHP's parser. As you can see, echo and exit are followed by different expressions. Exit is followed by nothing, `()` or an expression between parenthesis. Echo is simply followed by an expression:

```
unticked_statement:
        |       T_ECHO echo_expr_list ';'
        |       T_EXIT exit_expr        { ... }
...

exit_expr:
                /* empty */     { ... }
        |       '(' ')'         { ... }
        |       '(' expr ')'    { ... }
;


echo_expr_list:
                echo_expr_list ',' expr { ... }
        |       expr                    { ...; }
;
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP got a lot of inspiration from C and (*nix) shells.

The `echo` in shell does not require `()`'s.
And the `exit()` in C does (while `return` doesn't).

In `C`, `return` is a language construct (return from a function call), while `exit()` is a function performing the termination of a program.

PHP, as an interpreted language, was free to chose to consider `exit` as a language construct, or a function with `()`. It is a language construct that can be used as `exit;` or `exit(x);`

Answer (score 1):

exit can, it just does not take a string!?

> void **exit** ([ string *$status* ] )
>   void **exit** ([ int *$status* ] )

---

> If status is a string, this function
>   prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value
>   will be used as the exit status and
>   not printed. Exit statuses should be
>   in the range 0 to 254, the exit status
>   255 is reserved by PHP and shall not
>   be used. The status 0 is used to
>   terminate the program successfully.

Example of using exit without:

```
if(defined('EXIT_END'))
{
    exit;
}
```

Comment: `die` is completely equivalent to `exit`.

Comment: I like how you ignored your own copypasta: "If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting."

Comment: if i do exit("0") it will do the same as exit(0) apart from echo it out, and as for the die == exit, I need to check up on my manual more often.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because `exit` is a function that `echo` the first parameters and stop the script ?